# Displaying a byte[] file with wicket

Tags: java, byte, wicket

I want to be able to display on the browser a file with wicket. I have a form witch takes the id and storage area of the document, then by pressing the submit button, I would like to display the file on the browser if it's possible else download it.I get the file as a byte [], it's compulsory, I cannot have it another way. I searched a lot for some answers but the fact that I'am using wicket 6.8.0 is handicapand because every solution that I find uses some obsolete methods (for the 6.8.0 version).

My question is: Is there any one who can help me do this without changing the wicket version (I cannot change it). The solution doesn't have to be in wicket.

Sorry if my English is incorrect

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to process binary stream in Wicket like Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032469/how-to-process-binary-stream-in-wicket-like-servlet)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realised that the version of wicket that I'm using was the problem since some methods have changed. I updated my question in consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. For persons who want to do this with wicket 6.8.0, it's the solution. It's quite simple though. Here's the code:

```
WebResponse fileResponse = (WebResponse) getRequestCycle().getResponse();
fileResponse.setContentType(mimeType);
fileResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

fileResponse.write(myByteFile);
getRequestCycle().setResponse(fileResponse);
```

I get the file type by using the  [Tika API](http://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/).